# Dont changes option of select form when i createElement

Tags: javascript, html-select

Help.plz. I creating a tr "unitTableTr". Inside this tr i vreate a td. In one of created td, after i created a "unitTableTr" i need to put text from option. The text i put in td, but works only of the first option - 0.25. If i tried to take "option 2" and put "option 2" text in td, it put only "option 1" text.

**!**One more time: i need if i take "option 3" - in table must be "option 3" text, if "option 4" - "option 4" text.

What i did wrong in my code? Help plz

```
<form>
<select id="work1" style="float: left;"> 
<option>Выберите расценку:</option>
<option value="0">0,25 км</option>
<option value="1">0,25 -о 2,5 км</option>
<option value="2">2,5 - 4,5 км</option>
<option value="3">4,5 км</option>
<option value="4">schools</option>
<option value="5">base</option>
</select>
<div><span>+</span> 
<input type="text"> meters</div>
</form>

<a onclick="createUnit()"> + </a>
<a onclick="removeUnit()"> x </a>

</div>

<script>     

var table_index = 0; 

var a = document.getElementById("work1");
var b = a.options[a.selectedIndex].text;    

var c = document.createTextNode(b);
c.innerHTML = b;
text3.appendChild(c);

function createUnit() {

var unitTableTr = document.createElement('tr');
var unitTableTrTd_1 = document.createElement('td');
table_index++; 

var td_1_p = document.createTextNode(table_index );
unitTableTrTd_1.appendChild(td_1_p);
unitTableTr.appendChild(unitTableTrTd_1); 

var unitTableTrTd_2 = document.createElement('td');
var text2 = document.createTextNode("Reconstruction ");
var p = document.createElement("p"); 
var text3 = document.createTextNode(c.innerHTML);
p.id ="text3";
unitTableTrTd_2.appendChild(p);
unitTableTr.appendChild(unitTableTrTd_2);
p.appendChild(text2);
p.appendChild(text3);

var unitTableTrTd_3 = document.createElement('td');
unitTableTr.appendChild(unitTableTrTd_3);
var unitTableTrTd_4 = document.createElement('td');
unitTableTr.appendChild(unitTableTrTd_4);
var unitTableTrTd_5 = document.createElement('td');
unitTableTr.appendChild(unitTableTrTd_5);
begin_table.appendChild(unitTableTr);

}


</script>
```

Comment: When I see code like this, it makes me appreciate jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that your issue is being caused by the order of execution.

Your code is not working because ***the below code is only executed once, on page load***:

```
var b = a.options[a.selectedIndex].text;    

var c = document.createTextNode(b);
c.innerHTML = b;
text3.appendChild(c);
```

In your code, you show this happening before the `createUnit()` function. So this will only run once - on page load. And when the page loads, the selected index is always the first item in the option's list.

From your english, it is hard to tell exactly how you want your program to work, however, you need to get the selected index every time that you want to create that element. By moving the above code into the `createUnit()` function it could fix your problem, but again... hard to tell what your program is doing without studying it longer.

Comment: YES. Sorry what i some hard explain what i need from code. But you was right. But if i past a  selected you code in function, function doesnt work. And i see the problem. It was in the last string of that selected code - "text3.appendChild(c);"

Comment: @DeniWassulmaier yes, I wasn't sure where you were getting `text3` from, but where you were originally calling it, there was no text3 variable. If this helped you click the check mark next to the answer.